# Why lying with fathers means death (not burial)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, death

> **וְשָׁכַבְתִּי עִם־אֲבֹתַי** וּנְשָׂאתַנִי מִמִּצְרַיִם וּקְבַרְתַּנִי בִּקְבֻרָתָם...׃
> **When I lie down with my fathers**, take me up from Egypt and bury me in their burial-place.” [Gen.47.30](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.47.30?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) (also in several other places).

As is clearly seen from the order of actions, Rashi deduces that "laying with fathers" means:

> "מָצִינוּ בְּכָל מָקוֹם לְשׁוֹן שְׁכִיבָה עִם אֲבוֹתָיו הִיא הַגְּוִיעָה וְלֹא הַקְּבוּרָה"

Assuming that our forefathers were aware of the "world of souls", or the afterlife, it would be plausible to use phrases like "reuniting with fathers", "meeting fathers", rejoicing with fathers", but surely not "lying down".

What can explain such a weird metaphor for death?

Comment: Why do you think it's a weird metaphor? Seems pretty normal to me... Maybe he's referring in the physical sense, even though they were aware of the afterlife...

Comment: @robev Because in Jewish Rabbinic tradition, death means the raising of the soul UP to heaven or Eden or whatever, not laying DOWN, which is frequently used for hell, like Korach.

Comment: You'll have to prove that that's always the case making this something that needs to be explained. Otherwise, the verse can be read, even according to rabbinic tradition, without issue.

Comment: Take a look at the Bartenura - https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.47.30?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Bartenura_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.47.30.1&lang2=bi

Comment: @Dov Why don't you add it to your answer? And also, could you please explain those two interpreters in your own words, because I got a bit confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.47.30?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Bartenura_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.47.30.1&lang2=bi) on the verse explains as follows:

> ושכבתי עם אבותי וי"ו זה מחובר למעלה וכו' ואין לומ' ושכבתי השכיבני עם אבותי במערה וכו'. צריך לישב מה דוחקו של רש"י פשיטא שלא הייתי יכול לפרש שר"ל השכיבני עם אבותי במערה שכבר הוא אומ' וקברתני בקבורתם ועוד **דהא פשוט הוא שהוא לשון מיתה כמו שמביא רש"י בעצמו**. וי"ל דרש"י קשה לו מדוע שינה יעקב את לשונו שכשדבר אל יוסף אמ' ושכבתי עם אבותי וכשצוה את בניו אמר אני נאסף אל עמי ולכך הייתי יכול לפרש שזה ר"ל השכיבני עם אבותי במערה ומה שהוצרך לומ' אח"כ וקברתני בקבורתם כדי שלא יטעה שיקברוהו במקום אחר בארץ ישראל לכך אמ' שאינו יכול להיות שהרי כתי' אחריו ונשאתני ממצרים וקברתני בקבורתם וכלל בזה ב' ענינים האחד דמדכתי' ונשאתני ממצרים אח"כ ש"מ שאינו ר"ל השכיבני עם אבותי במערה שהרי ההולכה היא קודם הקבורה ועוד שהרי כתי' וקברתני בקבורתם ולא היה צריך לכתוב ושכבתי עם אבותי. ואח"כ הביא ראיה אחרת דאתי' אם תמצא לומ' מכח דקשיא דלעיל דמקרא מסורס הוא והרי הוא כאלו כתב ונשאתני ממצרים ושכבתי עם אבותי וקברתני בקבורתם ושיהיה וקברתני פי' **ושכבתי עם אבותי ע"כ אמ' מצינו בכל מקום שהשכיבה עם אבותיו היא הגויעה שהרי כתו' וישכב דוד עם אבותיו ויקבר בעיר דוד ושם אינו יכול לפרש שהשכיבה היא הקבורה שהרי ישי אביו נקבר בעיר בית לחם שהיתה עירו ודוד נקבר בירושלים**
>
> ושכבתי עם אבותי - The vav (used at the beginning of the word ושכבתי) connects to what was said before. It doesn't say, 'I lay down with my ancestors in a cave, etc.' We need to answer what Rashi's difficulty is. It is obvious that I could not interpret it as wanting to say 'When I lie down with my ancestors in a cave' as he already says 'Bury me in their burial place'. And furthermore, **it seems obvious that is an expression of death, like Rashi himself brings**. And we can say that Rashi's difficulty is why Yaakov changed his expression/language when he spoke to Yosef he said, "I will lie down with my ancestors' and when he commanded his sons he said, 'I am gathered to my people'. Therefore I am able to explain that it means to lie down with my ancestors in a cave, and that it was necessary to be said afterwards, 'and bury me in their burial place', so that he would not be mistaken for being buried elsewhere in the Land of Israel. Therefore it is not able to be written afterwards, 'And carry me from Egypt and bury me in their burial place'. So, two things can be inferred from this: From the fact that it writes 'and carry me from Egypt' after this we learn that it doesn't mean 'when I lie down with my ancestors in a cave', since the going/travelling happens before the burial. Moreover, when it writes 'bury me in their burial place' it doesn't then need to write, "When I lie down with my ancestors'. It must be that afterwards it bring another proof, since if you want to say based on the strength of the earlier question that the pasuk doesn't work, after all, he wrote "and carry me out of Egypt and when I lie with my ancestors and bury me in their burial place', and let it be 'and bury me' means 'when I lie with my fathers', **so we find in all places that 'When I lie down with my fathers' is a reference to dying. Since it writes 'And Dovid lay with his father and he was buried in the city of Dovid' and there he can not interpret that the lying is the burial because his father Yishai was buried in the city of Bethlehem which was his city and David was buried in Jerusalem [see [I Kings 2:10]](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.2.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)** (my translation)

So I believe what he is trying to say is that the way the verse is constructed can only be a reference to death as the words after would not work otherwise. It says וקברתני בקבורתם afterwards which can only happen after he had died otherwise if you understand the former as burial it would be repetitive and thus superfluous, and moreover, this is one of other examples where we see it as a reference to death as per the case by Dovid.

Comment: Thank you, it appears that you answered the wrong part (or I wasn't clear enough). R"B answers the "fathers" part, not "lying down". I have no problem with "fathers". If he answers about being buried with fathers, that contradicts Rashi. And what does "*one’s spirit would immediately head for the location assigned to it*" mean?

Comment: @AlBerko - I took out the Rabbeinu Bachya from my answer as it didn't sufficiently answer your question but I believe the Bartenura does a good job at addressing your difficulties?

Comment: Wait, he's merely re-stating Rashi, I don't see anything new he adds to the understanding of the phrase.

Comment: No he is validating Rashi - he is saying why it has to mean death and not burial, and brings another example of this phrase used in the context of death

Comment: Yes, but we already know that.